# Mostrar todas las columnas y 1 solo registro duplicado - Postgress

Tags: postgresql

trato de hacer una consulta en la que me muestre todas las columnas de la tabla, pero que me muestre solo 1 registro de los que haya duplicados.

No puedo usar DISTINC, ya que si 1 de mis registros contiene un dato diferente en alguna de mis columnas, este se mostrara duplicado.

Mi  Query actual es

`SELECT DISTINCT cbd.numero_celular, cbd.*  FROM contactos_bases_datos AS cbd JOIN campana_base_dato_relacion AS cbdr ON cbdr.id_base_dato = cbd.id_base_dato JOIN campana_plantilla_sms_relacion AS cpsm ON cpsm.id_base_dato = cbdr.id_base_dato::INTEGER ORDER BY cbd.ID DESC;`

Hacer esta consulta me funciona, pero luego debo recorrer el resultado de la consulta y eliminar los duplicados en mi backend. Y siento que seria demasiado ineficiente.

Me interesa mostrar todas las columnas de la tabla, y solo 1 registro de los varios duplicados con numero que encuentre.

Gracias.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Como lo indica, si DISTINCT no elimina filas es porque alguno de los datos de las columnas es distinto. Debería indicar en la pregunta cual es el subconjuto de columnas que asume para la unicidad, y de las otras columnas que no participan en la unicidad cual sería el ordenamiento para seleccionar la que represente el grupo

Comment: @MauricioOrtega , aun no tengo muchos conocimientos en SQL, me sugiere que encuentre la manera de hacer la condicion con los grupos ?

Comment: A lo que me refiero es que en el código que actualmente tiene con el que debe "recorrer el resultado de la consulta y eliminar los duplicados" tiene alguna condición sobre un subgrupo de las columnas con as cuales determina cuando "se repite una fila". Ese subgrupo de columnas es al que me refiero

Comment: @MauricioOrtega Muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda, pero no logre entender :(

Answer (score 0):

Existen varias formas de resolver ese problema pero sin duda la mas eficiente es user where exits :

```
SELECT column-names
  FROM table-name
 WHERE EXISTS 
      (SELECT column-name
         FROM table-name
        WHERE condition)
```

Si Necesitas más información te dejo este link:
[https://dofactory.com/sql/where-exists#:~:text=SQL%20WHERE%20EXISTS%20Statement%20What%20does%20WHERE%20EXISTS,EXISTS%20condition%20is%20commonly%20used%20with%20correlated%20subqueries](https://dofactory.com/sql/where-exists#:%7E:text=SQL%20WHERE%20EXISTS%20Statement%20What%20does%20WHERE%20EXISTS,EXISTS%20condition%20is%20commonly%20used%20with%20correlated%20subqueries).